# Concatenate multiple char* in a row using strcat

Tags: c, strcat

I'm currently trying to concatenate multiple 'strings' in a row in my server program using `strcat`.
The concerning part of the code is as follows:
I successfully get the year, month, day, and filename sent by the client because it prints out well.

My strings are initialized as follows:

```
    char username[MAX_USERNAME_SIZE];
    char filename[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
    char path[MAX_FILEPATH_SIZE];
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];
    char year[4], month[2], day[2];
    ...
    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, &username, MAX_USERNAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("Serveur: recv username");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        username[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("Serveur: username: %s\n", username); 
        /* create user's repository if it doesn't exist yet*/

        // 3) get date from client
        if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, year, 4, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Serveur: recv year");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        year[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("year: %s\n", year);
        if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, month, 2, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Serveur: recv month");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        month[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("month: %s\n", month);
        if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, day, 2, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Serveur: recv day");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        day[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("day: %s\n", day);
        // get filename from client
        if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, filename, MAX_FILENAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1)
        {
            perror("Serveur: recv filename");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        filename[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("Serveur: filename: %s\n", filename);
```

But I'm getting issues when I try to concatenate properly all the strings as shown.

```
        // create user repository
        strcpy(path, argv[1]);
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n", path);
        strcat(path, "/");
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n", path);

        strcat(path, username);
        strcat(path, "/");
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, username:%s\n", path, username);
        my_mkdir(path, MODE);

        strcat(path, year);
        strcat(path, "/");
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, year: %s\n", path, year);
        my_mkdir(path, MODE);

        strcat(path, month);
        strcat(path, "/");
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, month: %s\n", path, month);
        my_mkdir(path, MODE);

        strcat(path, day);
        strcat(path, "/");
        printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, day: %s\n", path, day);
        my_mkdir(path, MODE);

        strcat(path, filename);
}
```

And after I do so, username, year,and month doesn't print well surprisingly.
Here is the outpout when I execute my code (I know for sure filename is OK because the file I retrieve from client is saved under the correct name):

```
Serveur: connection recieved from client 127.0.0.1
Serveur: username: student
year: 95
month: 5
day: 11
Serveur: filename: tux.png
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1/
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1//
, username:
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1///
, year: 
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1////
, month: 
Serveur: Path: ./Test0/Test1////11/
, day: 11
```

I'm really missing to visualize clearly where I'm wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your favorite debugger will help you here. If you provide a [mcve] (that means a standalone program with test data without the `recv` stuff), we can help, but doing this, you probably will find the bug yourself.

Comment: You don't show us how `path` is defined, so could easily be a problem there

Comment: The bug is in some code you didn't post. What code is executed between the two code block? BTW: `recv(new_fd, &username,...` I guess you don't the `&`.

Comment: How are your buffers defined? `char username[??....`

Comment: @ChrisTurner  I achieve the desired result when I change the size of year, month, and day respectively to 5, 3, 3 in both client and server program and remove every  ´ var[numbytes] ='\0' ´ (where var = {year, month, or day}) in server program. However, I'm still not understanding why. This also mean I'm sending '\0' from client to server. Isn't it superfluous?

Comment: @4386427 no code is executed between the two last code block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not giving enough space to your strings. You still don't show exactly how all of them are declared, but there are enough examples to demonstrate the problem, like this one.

```
char year[4]
```

The above can only hold 3 characters - the 4th is space to store the `\0` terminating character.

Here you're telling your code to read 4 bytes from the socket, which it will do and then `numbytes` will be equal to 4...

```
    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, year, 4, 0)) == -1)
```

...and then you use `numbytes` to add the NUL terminator...

```
    year[numbytes] = '\0';
```

...but `year[4]` is beyond the bounds of your array, which causes undefined behaviour. It might appear that `year` has a valid year in it, but then the rest of your code happens and weird stuff happens because you're also making the same mistake for all your other strings too.

To hold 4 characters plus the NUL, you need to declare `year` with a minimum of 5, like this...

```
char year[5]
```

... but is your computer so short of memory that you need to be so frugal? Better to give it more than it needs or read it into a buffer that has plenty of space and allocate enough memory to create the right sized string if space is at a premium, like this example shows.

```
char *year;
char buffer[100];
if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buffer, 4, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("Serveur: recv year");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
buffer[numbytes] = '\0';
year=malloc(numbytes+1);
strcpy(year,buffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

show the code which shows the memory allocations for username, year, month and day. Make sure they are not overlapped or shared.

try

```
sprintf(path,"%s/%s/%s/%s/%s/",argv[1],username,year,month,day);
```

Or change like,

```
 strcpy(path, argv[1]);
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n", path);
 strcat(path, "/");
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n", path);


 if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, &username, MAX_USERNAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1){
        perror("Serveur: recv username");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 username[numbytes] = '\0';
 printf("Serveur: username: %s\n", username); 
 strcat(path, username);
 strcat(path, "/");
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, username:%s\n", path, username);
 my_mkdir(path, MODE);    

 /* create user's repository if it doesn't exist yet*/

 // 3) get date from client
 if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, year, 4, 0)) == -1){
     perror("Serveur: recv year");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 year[numbytes] = '\0';
 printf("year: %s\n", year);
 strcat(path, year);
 strcat(path, "/");
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, year: %s\n", path, year);
 my_mkdir(path, MODE);

 if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, month, 2, 0)) == -1){
     perror("Serveur: recv month");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 month[numbytes] = '\0';
 printf("month: %s\n", month);

 strcat(path, month);
 strcat(path, "/");
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, month: %s\n", path, month);
 my_mkdir(path, MODE);


 if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, day, 2, 0)) == -1){
     perror("Serveur: recv day");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 day[numbytes] = '\0';
 printf("day: %s\n", day);

 strcat(path, day);
 strcat(path, "/");
 printf("Serveur: Path: %s\n, day: %s\n", path, day);
 my_mkdir(path, MODE);

 // get filename from client
 if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, filename, MAX_FILENAME_SIZE, 0)) == -1){
     perror("Serveur: recv filename");
     return EXIT_FAILURE;
 }
 filename[numbytes] = '\0';
 printf("Serveur: filename: %s\n", filename);
 strcat(path, filename);
```